# How do I use getSharedPreferences without extending Activity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have a GamePanel class which extends SurfaceView so I cant extend Activity for SharedPreferences. How do I use getSharedPreferences with out extending the class?

I have already tried:

```
SharedPreferences sp = Activity.getSharedPreferences("MyScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

However, I get an error which says "cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Pass Context when creating object of `GamePanel`

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise the Sharedpreferences in your Application class as a static variable and then use that in every non-activity class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        return sharedPreferences;
    }

    public void setSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        setSharedPreferences(MyApplication.this
            .getSharedPreferences("MyScore",getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Now whenever you want to access the sharedprefs in a static context, you can always use it like this:

```
    String value = MyApplication.getSharedPreferences().getString("key","");
```